# How can i make boostrap table enable sorting and paging using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap table for showing data with Javascript : "Call a bootstrap table with id table with JavaScript."

Sample code i am uisng is below

```
    console.log('data', data); //Showing the table value through console
    $(target).html('<table id="data_table"></table>');
    $('#data_table').bootstrapTable(data);
```

The data output is shown in the console image..https://www.screencast.com/t/ZVpKlc1ZoJ

Table is coming fine but missing the sorting and paging.
How can i do it through Javascript only?

Comment: Have you included the dataTable.js file?

Comment: @LalaByte Yes i have already added bootstrap-table.js and for data i am passing the value dynamically.You can see the data value through the console.Inside the object there are two arrays named columns and data as it required for Javascript.https://www.screencast.com/t/GBSynyItiF

Comment: Finally i used datatables